# Fixed Gradient With Css3 in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, gradient, fixed

I am looking to put a css3 gradient for the full length of the window, and when the window scrolls, the gradient would scoll with it.  I cannot get it to work in IE9?
Here is my code.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
 body 
{    
    font: 100%/1.4 Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-attachment: fixed !important;    
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#8fc2ed, endColorstr=#ffffff);    
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top -90deg, #8fc2ed, #ffffff);    
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#8fc2ed), to(#ffffff));

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think you need to capitalize 'str' in your filter. So it would be startColorStr and endColorStr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the filter is not a CSS background image, so `background-attachment` doesn't apply to it.  You could try adding a 100% height element with the filter on it behind your page content and setting that to `position: fixed`.

Comment: Hello robertc,  Thank you very much!  This makes perfect sense now that I look at what you are saying.  I appreciate the help.